# Problem with checking updates sudo apt update

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I would like to update my linux 22.04 LTS version, but there 404 error occurs.
How to fix it?

command: sudo apt update

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                 
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease     
Ign:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/system76/pop/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/system76/pop/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/system76/pop/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

linux 5.19.0-051900-generic x86_64
```

I also tried to delete this pop~

```
HP-ENVY:~# sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ansible/ansible
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description:
Ansible is a radically simple IT automation platform that makes your applications and systems easier to deploy. Avoid writing scripts or custom code to deploy and update your applications— automate in a language that approaches plain English, using SSH, with no agents to install on remote systems.

http://ansible.com/

If you face any issues while installing Ansible PPA, file an issue here:
https://github.com/ansible-community/ppa/issues
More info: https://launchpad.net/~ansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible
Removing repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                 
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                
Ign:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/system76/pop/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease               
Err:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/system76/pop/ubuntu jammy Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/system76/pop/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried this one:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

but still there is a problem in logs:

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/system76/pop/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
```

How to fix it, delete this one, is it necessary?

Comment: Looks like you are on Popos and not Ubuntu.

Comment: is it possible look at my post again

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)   *You're not using a Ubuntu kernel, but 3rd party kernel from System76 (Pop OS); if your system was Ubuntu - it's now frakensystem*

Comment: How to change 3rd party kernel to ubuntu kernel?